# Using arduino IDE with USBasp

Tags: avrdude

I'm trying to upload a Blink example from Arduino IDE to an atmega8a via USBasp. I have edited the boards.txt file with the specifications of the atmega8a, and I am using the "Upload with programmer" option.

AVRdude gives no errors, only a warning that my usbasp firmware needs an update. I assume the code is uploaded, but it does not execute. My fuse settings are hfuse - 0xc0, lfuse - 0x9f, but i have tried different ones to no avail.

Comment: Are the libraries you're using compatible with the 8a, and are you compiling for the 8a? You can't just upload Arduino code to an arbitrary AVR without making sure the toolchain supports it first.

Comment: I selected a board i have previously added to Arduino IDE.

Comment: Since Arduino doesn't support atmega8a by default, it would help if you told us what board that is in the question, then.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't answer earlier, but  I still hope for a reply. Currently, I've set it up in Arduino IDE 1.6.5 using board Arduino NG with atmega8 selected as processor. I already spent quite a lot of time playing with the board setting in boards.txt, but there could have been something I've missed.